# Does xsd.exe identify numerical fields?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd.exe

When I use `xsd.exe` to generate C# classes for a given XML with minimal metadata, does it recognize numerical attributtes (and InnerTextes)  and map them to properties of numerical types (ie: int, double)?

Comment: What have you tried? Feed it a simple XML file with the types you would like to test with and see the result. Would be faster than asking here.

Comment: @Oded Maybe faster for me, but if every person that runs into the same doubt had to test it, I think they would find faster just to google it and find it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test:

```
<test>
    <i>123</i>
    <f>12.3</f>
    <s>abc</s>
</test>
```

then:

```
xsd test.xml
xsd test.xsd /c
```

gives:

```
  <xs:element name="test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="i" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="f" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="s" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

and:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string i {
    get {
        return this.iField;
    }
    set {
        this.iField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string f {
    get {
        return this.fField;
    }
    set {
        this.fField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string s {
    get {
        return this.sField;
    }
    set {
        this.sField = value;
    }
}
```

So I'm going to vote "not very reliably, if at all".